# Getting different values from a row in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to to look up the values from a row which column1=certainvalue that the user chooses in the sheet, how can I do that? I've looked it up but I can't seem to find anything regarding that.

Comment: click to a column, type `=`, and then click the column which is the value is what you expected.

Comment: if you are looking for `VLOOKUP()` then show us some of your column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need `VLOOKUP` function something as:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,A2:B6,2,TRUE)
```

this formula looks for the value in `Cell E2` (i.e. name4) in the `Column A` and will return value from `Column B`

See image for reference

[image]